# Locust- repeat the user list

Tags: python, locust

In the following locust file, we are sending two user details. This works fine when we run with 2 users. However, when we run the same with more than 2 users (for example 5 users), then it starts failing for that remaining new users ( i.e 3 users).

```
import json
from locust import User, HttpUser, task, between, SequentialTaskSet, 
HttpLocust

USER_CREDENTIALS = [
 ("abc@xyz.com", "Yahoo@123"),
 ("xyz@xyz.com", "Yahh-69-Wrap")
]

class CLMLoginTaskSet(SequentialTaskSet):
  hostname_app2 = "http://app2.stage.cloud.local"
  hostname_app1 = "http://app1.stage.cloud.local"
  port = "8090"
  username = "NOT_FOUND"
  password = "NOT_FOUND"
  access_token_value1 = None

 @task
 def userlist(self):
    if len(USER_CREDENTIALS) > 0:
        self.username, self.password = USER_CREDENTIALS.pop()

 @task
 def generate_clm_token(self):
    print("username", self.username)
    print("password", self.password)
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    clm_response = 
    self.client.post(self.hostname_app2+":"+self.port+"/oauth2/access? 
 grant_type=password&username="+self.username+"&password="+self.password", 
     headers=headers)
    print("CLM Response", clm_response.text)
    json_clm_response = clm_response.json()
    access_token_value = json_clm_response['access_token']
    print("This is the access token value", access_token_value)
    self.access_token_value1 = access_token_value
    

   class CLMLogin(HttpUser):
    tasks = [CLMLoginTaskSet]
    host = ""
    wait_time = between(1, 2)
```

[image]

It should repeat and use the same user list if we start the load test with more users. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 credentials and popping them on start. `pop` removes the item from the list so after your first 2 users the list is empty and has nothing to pop. Try increasing credentials if you still want to use pop method or you can just access one credential with `random.choice` method without popping so next user can still use that. Beware that some users will have same user so they can affect each other depending on how the system works.